# Changing Account Password (using Parity)

Tags: parity, accounts, password

This is such a silly question but my eyes are tired from searching and not finding the answer.  (I see some posts that say it is not possible with Parity but only with Geth and that does not seem likely.)

So: how do I change the passphrase for an account (in .../keys) in Parity using the command line,  RPC, and/or javascript console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the doc on github,you just use rpc api (parity_changepassword), you can refer to https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity_accounts-module#parity_changepassword